# Custom field type to replace MultiLookup in Sharepoint 2010. Where to inherit from?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, custom-field-type

I am developing a custom field type which should look like a MultiLookup (two Listboxes, "add" and "remove" - Buttons). But I do not want to save that data in the List that contains the field. In other words: There should be happening completely custom code.

I have an idea how to solve it, but am unsure of what type I should derive my custom control from. Or doesn't this matter when I override FieldRenderingControl and I can just use

```
public class MyCustomField:SPFieldText
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter as long as you don't save data in the list. Choose the one with the smallest footprint, boolean or so (I don't exactly know the name).